# Results address of empty cell in Excel sheet using XSSF

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, xssf

I am reading an Excel sheet using POI's XSSF . The Excel sheet has thousands of rows of user information like user name,  address, age, department etc.

I can read and write the Excel sheet successfully but i want to locate empty/null cell's address  and want to print it as result in another sheet

example result what i want is:

```
Empty cell  : C5
Empty cell  : E7
Empty cell  : H8
```

Thanks and appreciate for discussions and replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for both Null and Blank cells. Null cells are ones that have never been used, Blank ones are ones that have been used or styled in some way that Excel has decided to keep them around in the file

The easiest way to control this fetching is with a [MissingCellPolicy](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html). Your code can then be something like:

```
Row r = getRow(); // Logic here to get the row of interest

// Iterate over all cells in the row, up to at least the 10th column
int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), 10);

for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
      Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
      } else {
         // Do something useful with the cell's contents
         // eg...
         System.out.println("There is data in cell " + (new CellReference(c)).formatAsString());
      }
}
```

You can find more on this in the [POI docs on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)

Comment: thanks for ur reply,i want to print empty cells address,even iterate over all cells

Comment: Switch that for `Row.RETURN_NULL_AS_BLANK`, then switch on type of blank cell and you should be done then!

Comment: .everything is ok how to fetch the address of that blank cell.pls help me

Comment: Use `CellReference`, it'll convert it for you, see my edit for an example

Comment: as  verbose-mode answer i used 'CellReference' in  cell.setCellValue but if next cell is null it shows exception as null pointer

Answer (score 1):

As far as I unterstood your question right, this should do the trick:

```
XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) row.getCell( index );
if( cell == null )
{
  cell = (XSSFCell) row.createCell( index );
}
if( cell.getStringCellValue().trim().isEmpty() )
{
  String cellRef = CellReference.convertNumToColString( cell.getColumnIndex() );
  System.err.println( "Empty cell found: " + cellRef
          + Integer.toString( row.getRowNum() ) );
}
```

Comment: verbose-mode  Thanks for quick reply ..yep it is nice trick but shows first empty cell thats it

Comment: Does it work for you? I yes, do not forget to accept the answer. If no, feel free to post me your questions.

Comment: verbose yes this trick is really helpful for me to achieve my result thats geart..